# An argument named "resource_group_name" is not expected here

Tags: azure, terraform

I was looking at a GitHub project [ibm-cloud-architecture/terraform-openshift4-azure](https://github.com/ibm-cloud-architecture/terraform-openshift4-azure) to install OpenShift using Terraform.

Using Terraform 1.3.7 this project fails on the following code

```
resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "internal_lb_controlplane_pool_v4" {
  count = var.use_ipv4 ? 1 : 0

  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  loadbalancer_id     = azurerm_lb.internal.id
  name                = var.cluster_id
}
```

with the message

> Error: Unsupported argument
> on vnet/internal-lb.tf line 40, in resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool"  internal_lb_controlplane_pool_v4":
> 40:   resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
>
> An argument named "resource_group_name" is not expected here.

Why is this code failing? How can we specify the name of a resource group with the current version of Terraform and Azure?

Answer (score 0):

If you check docs for [azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/lb_backend_address_pool) you will see that it does not take `resource_group_name` argument. So it should be:

```
resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "internal_lb_controlplane_pool_v4" {
  count = var.use_ipv4 ? 1 : 0
  loadbalancer_id     = azurerm_lb.internal.id
  name                = var.cluster_id
}
```

Comment: Okay but now my resources end up in a resource group with a dynamic, generated name. How do I then configure the resource group name?

Comment: I'm guessing based on the `azurerm_lb` placement.

Comment: @onknows You set `resource_group_name` in `azurerm_lb`.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was caused because of syntax error.  There `resource_group_name` is not required.

```
resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "example" {
  loadbalancer_id = azurerm_lb.example.id
  name            = "BackEndAddressPool"
}
```

here is the code [reference](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/lb_backend_address_pool) and replicated the same

main tf as follow:

```
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "********"
  location = "West Europe"
}
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "example" {
  name                = "swarnaPublicIPForLB"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
}

resource "azurerm_lb" "example" {
  name                = "swarnaTestLoadBalancer"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = "swanraPublicIPAddress"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.example.id
  }
}

resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "example" {
  loadbalancer_id = azurerm_lb.example.id
  name            = "BackEndAddressPool"
}
```

upon plan and apply
[image]

[image]

From Portal
[image]